# polymorpishm in java abstract class

Tags: java

We cannot create objects from abstract classes in Java. But there is a part that I do not understand. I have an abstract class called "GameCharacter" in my project. A resource told me to write the code in my assignment like this, but I don't understand, did we not use an object in parentheses(GameCharacter gamechar) Didn't we use an object called gameChar in ?

```
public void setPlayer(GameCharacter gamechar){

}
```

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where inheritance comes into play: `gamechar` can be any instance of `GameCharacter`, or any class that extends it. You may not be able to directly create a `GameCharacter` instance, but this method's logic should work with any instance of any concrete class that extends it.